# I want to display image from database when checkbox selected

Tags: c#, .net, image, display, checked

I have a  Product_table with image field and Is publish field. I want to display image from database when checkbox selected and when not selected Image will hide.

How can I do this in MVC.net?

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: Admin can publish  image when need otherwise image will not show.